# Почему не сохраняются данные в бд после перезапуска приложения?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nw</groupId>
    <artifactId>BookingDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BookingDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Entity:

```
package com.nw.booking;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class HotelBooking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String hotelName;
    private double pricePerNight;
    private int nbOfNights;

    public HotelBooking(String hotelName, double pricePerNight, int nbOfNights) {
        super();
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
        this.pricePerNight = pricePerNight;
        this.nbOfNights = nbOfNights;
    }

    public HotelBooking(){}

    public String getHotelName() {
        return hotelName;
    }
    public double getPricePerNight() {
        return pricePerNight;
    }
    public int getNbOfNights() {
        return nbOfNights;
    }
    public double getTotalPrice(){
        return pricePerNight * nbOfNights;
    }
    public long getId(){
        return id;
    }

}
```

repisitory:

```
package com.nw.booking;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BookingRepository extends JpaRepository<HotelBooking, Long>  {
    List<HotelBooking> findByPricePerNightLessThan(double price);
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./bookings.db
```

CommandLineRunner:

```
package com.nw.booking;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DatabaseSeeder implements CommandLineRunner  {
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseSeeder(BookingRepository bookingRepository){
        this.bookingRepository = bookingRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        List<HotelBooking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Marriot", 200.50, 3));
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Ibis", 90, 4));
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Novotel", 140.74, 1));
        bookingRepository.save(bookings);
    }

}
```

Если в application.properties добавить

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

то вылетает ошибка

Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Буду очень признателен за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение по умолчанию для `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` - это `create-drop`. То есть создать при запуске и удалить при завершении. Значение `validate` служит для проверки того, что схема БД соответствует сущностям JPA. Так как база пустая в момент запуска, проверка не проходит и вы получаете ошибку. Чтобы создать схему при запуске, но не удалять, укажите просто `create`.

[Соответствующий раздел документации.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

Comment: Спасибо, дружище. Я сначала запустил приложение со значением create, а потом изменил значение на validate. Блин полтора дня просидел с этим....